# Do these two metrics give rise to the same topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology

We define metric $d_1$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ as follows :

For $x=(x_1,x_2),y=(y_1,y_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $d_1(x,y)=|x_1-x_2|+|y_1-y_2|$.

Then is the metric topology $J_1$ induced by $d_1$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ same with the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

I am sure it should be but I am asking for being convinced of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the taxicab metric. The basic open sets look like squares, while the usual open sets look like discs.

To prove two metrics induce the same topology, you need to show that, given a point in one metric ball $B$, you can find a ball $B'$ w.r.t. other metric that contains the point and is contained in $B$.

This boils down to showing each point in a disc is contained in a square in the disc, and every point in a square is contained in a disc in the square.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I see that those two topology(one is usual topology, another is taxicab topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are same in for all $n$. (Am I right?)

Comment: @user29422 Indeed, all finite products.